# Appending lists to a result list keeps replacing the last one appended

Tags: python, sorting

I want to append a list (`arrCopy`) to a list-of-lists (result). But with each `append`, the current list replaces the former list, so that the list of lists only has the current list.

```
def insertionSort1(n, arr):
    arrCopy = arr[:]
    last = arr[-1]
    result = []

    for ind, num in enumerate(reversed(arr[:-1])):

        print('ind',ind, 'num',num, 'arrCopy', arrCopy, 'result',result)

        if num>=last:
            arrCopy[len(arr)-1-ind] = num
            result.append(arrCopy)
        else:
            arrCopy[len(arr)-1-ind] = last
            result.append(arrCopy)
            break

    print(result)

    for nums in result: 
        print(' '.join(str(n) for n in nums))

insertionSort1(5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

`arrCopy` is appended as a reference, meaning a pointer to the array in memory. If the array in memory changes, it will show up everywhere it is referenced.

You need to store a copy of the array. You can do that like this: 
`result.append(arrCopy[:])` This will create a new array in memory that is not affected by changes in `arrCopy`

Comment: I like this answer more than mine, btw - no need to use deepcopy, but same result.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't 'freezing' arrCopy when appending, so everytime you add the list by name, it changes as the result changes.

Try importing the copy module and using deepcopy like I have done.

```
import copy

def insertionSort1(n, arr):
    arrCopy = copy.deepcopy(arr[:])
    last = arr[-1]
    result = []
for ind, num in enumerate(reversed(arr[:-1])):


    print('ind',ind, 'num',num, 'arrCopy', arrCopy, 'result',result)
    if num>=last:
        arrCopy[len(arr)-1-ind]=num
        result.append(copy.deepcopy(arrCopy))
    else:
        arrCopy[len(arr)-1-ind]=last
        result.append(copy.deepcopy(arrCopy))
        break

print(result)

for nums in result:
    print(' '.join(str(n) for n in nums))

def main():
    insertionSort1(5, [2, 4, 6, 8, 3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```